# Entity framework inserting always null ID

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, frameworks, entity

I'm trying to use Entity Framework to save changes into DB.

```
  using (var context = new Entities())
  {
     USERS user = new USERS() { NAME = name, PASSWORD = password };
     context.USERS.Add(user);
     context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

It always throws an  exception as it is inserting 0 as primary key:

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (\"SYSTEM\".\"USERS\".\"ID\")
>
> ORA-06512: at line 4

Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:

USERS class has following properties:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
```

I have set StoreGeneratedPattern on Identity and it still inserts ID as 0

Comment: Can you share your model class. This generally happens because you have not annotated the ID property as [Key]

Comment: What does the `USERS` class look like? Have you defined a primary key? Is it set to be a number or GUID?

Comment: Looks like `users.id` is expected to be an identity column. Is it?

Comment: By the way, `system` is reserved for Oracle internals and you shouldn't use it for your own objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "DatabaseName".SEQ_user_ID  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 18000 CACHE 2 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL ;
```

And a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DatabaseName".TRI_SEQ_user_ID
               BEFORE INSERT ON version
               REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT ID.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
END;
```

with these two functions, you can add new entries into the database without specifying an ID

Answer (score 0):

İf you dont use code first or db first oracle dont create be sequnce
You try it trigger with sequence

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER 
"a"."IHALEYOL"
before insert on "a"."IHALEYOL"
for each row
begin
  select "a"."SQ_DIREK".nextval into :new."ID" from dual;
end;
```

seq :

```
 create sequence SQ_YETKI
minvalue 1
maxvalue 9999999999999999999999999999
start with 221
increment by 1
cache 20;
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried to generate model from DB as Code-Frist, still inserting 0 as ID. Here is primary key configuration:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<USERS>()
                .HasKey<int>(e => e.ID);
```

and entity properties:

```
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string NAME { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this problem by granting all System Privileges (except SYSDBA and SYSOPER) to the connection string User:

[image: Edit the user's privileges using Oracle SQL Developer]

I'm guessing you were problably missing a permission to use the sequence, but I'm not sure which one exactly.